# Why didn't Time Crystal burn out after opening first wormhole?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In *Star Trek: Discovery*, the only reason Burnham was going to have one way trip because time crystal was going to burn out after opening wormhole.

But, in the season 2 finale, we saw that

> she opened multiple wormholes successfully to the past before jumping to the future.

How was she able to do that?

Comment: She jumped into past.

Comment: @Oni So? Any wormhole is a wormhole.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Burnham was making shorter jumps into the recent past (literally writing her own history)
> 2. Only Burnham was making those jumps

Also remember that

> the plan was to take Burnham *and Discovery* to the future. That trip was one-way. As we see with Burnham's mother, single person jumps don't seem to take anywhere near as much energy.